# The bijective smooth function from a smooth manifold $M$ with $dimM \geq 2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ do not exist

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to show that: there exists no bijective smooth function from a connected smooth manifold $M$ with $dimM \geq 2$ to the real line $\mathbb{R}$. This seems to be easy but I cannot solve it, can someone help me?

Moreover, I think there are some kind of generalizations, so I wonder: is it true that "the existence of bijective smooth map from manifolds $M$ to $N$" implies that "$dimM = dimN$?

Comment: Try using the inverse function theorem for functions $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta But if the $df$ is not invertible at some points, what can I do?

Comment: Here's a hint: There must be some point $x\in M$ so that $df_x$ maps surjectively to $\Bbb R$. Can you apply the Implicit Function Theorem?

Comment: $df_x$ can *never* be invertible. I am not sure what @RaulFernandesHorta is referring to. Perhaps he was thinking of the direction I suggested in my hint.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh! I think I know how to solve it.

Comment: @Quzs Then you should answer your own question.